# Initializing TypeScript objects only with their class-specific properties using partials

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Consider the following example:

```js
const assign = <T, K extends keyof T>(...args: T[]): T =>
    args.reduce((result, current) =>
        (Object.keys(current) as K[]).reduce((target, key) => {
            target[key] = current[key];
            return target;
        }, result)
        , args[0]);

class Base {
    str1: string = '';
    str2: string = '';

    constructor(data: Partial<Base>) {
        assign(this, data);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    str3: string = '';

    constructor(data: Partial<Derived>) {
        super(data);
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}

const derivedObj = new Derived({ str1: 'text', str3: 'new prop' })
const baseObject = new Base(derivedObj);

console.log(baseObject);
// Outputs:
// Data { "str1": "text", "str2": "", "str3": "new prop" }
```

The base class comprises less properties than the derived class. The base class constructor accepts a `Partial<Base>` which is also compatible with the `Partial<Derived>` type. This results in extraneous properties being assigned to the base class object when passing an object of type `Partial<Derived>`.

**Is there a way to initialize the base class object only with its class-specific properties (`str` and `str2` and *not `str3`*)?**

*PS: There are a lot of seemingly similar discussions on GitHub and here. So far, I haven't found any which tackles this exact problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
const assign = <T, K extends keyof T>(...args: T[]): T =>
    args.reduce((result, current) =>
        (Object.keys(args[0]) as K[]).reduce((target, key) => {
            if (current[key] !== undefined) target[key] = current[key];
            return target;
        }, result)
    , args[0]);
```

See this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?strictFunctionTypes=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=25#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhCBLA5mGBeGAeAKgGhgGkYBTADylLABMIYBrUgTxADMZcA%20ACgDoBcAE4oIALk4BtALoBKCbkxcAsACgYG%20CIh8hpGgFdgpHjz0QDAGyiFgBoXrBRZStZvcweAeQBGAK1JgKD4mZggeYVFJAAY5eHoiGVldfSMTHihI0htGFhcMLhgAbzcPMqQOHjsHaihJUOkYAEIMLANaUjYkMH0XTJFs%20pZGrGrHOoaAblKy9z0oe3R%20lGzp9VmAX0JzK2cZj0JIiBi5NbVgSwR6ACEEUmL96CEARgkn7pRMGAByb7X3J4AJjeUCEHy%20vzO6w0oEgoKMUBAQh4NDgmQkAAVhFAkHBLNhbhBSFwXCVoR4rqgwBkABZICCEVGZWT-TQbNTs1TnS6IGAAEVIYIAbvoyJRqHQYIT7mSAaCAMwgsFgT5YSFqfawp4IpEotFwTHY3H4gXC-Qkh7kgEGAAOgr1zNZZV8ASCfEpaFp9MZ%20pZ%2005nPO4GgMBogqQIpoLq%20PQA7vzw5GeEUYE9Xj8qJRvoQnoqfnGYDahCAbd8YBtZEG4TAfHcXYFYFgC9KUYn9C6-VzVFqQJZSHxLCAUDxa0T60EWUA)

Comment: Thank you, looking at your code, I realize I was so close. :)